# Design a triangular wave generator using a sinusoidal input

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger, integrator, sinusoidal

I've been going through online assignments regarding circuit designs. I've gotten a bit stuck on this one:

> Using a **sinusoidal** input voltage of amplitude *5 V* and frequency *100 Hz*, I need a **triangular** wave output with *peak-to-peak* voltage of *20 V*. The external biasing voltages are assumed to be *+15 V* and *-15 V*, **saturation voltage** magnitude of *13.5 V* and **maximum output current** of *25 mA*.

I thought of using a Schmitt trigger to first convert the sinusoidal wave to a square wave, and then use an integrator to refine it into triangular wave using suitable capacitors and resistors.

I've not been able to do so.

This is the design I've come up with:

[image]

This isn't working. There might be minor errors, but I'm not able to find them.

Can someone help me with the design, and the possible values of the resistors and capacitors I should use in the integrator and Schmitt trigger circuits?

Comment: hint: your operating system has a functionality for screenshots. You don't need to use your phone for photos of the screen :)

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thanks.

Comment: with that out the way, what's the waveform you're getting out of this?

Comment: "*This isn't working*" won't win any prizes for Troubleshooter of the Month. What exactly ***is*** it doing.

Comment: Hysteresis feedback is probably 13.5/2=6.5V while sine wave is only 5V. Will it trigger?

Comment: @Transistor I 'm not getting any output as such, otherwise it would've been shown in the pic. I'm using Falstad simulator to serve my purpose.

Comment: @AJN I don't have the input and output waveforms as such, only the statement as I've mentioned. Plus, the Schmitt trigger hasn't been given explicitly, it's just that I'm using it to convert it to square wave at first. Probably, I should use better resistor values for the tripping points, as the square wave would have a duty cycle of 0.5, I think.

Comment: Falstad allows for the link to be shared (I think). Perhaps add it to the question?

Comment: Yes export full link only in answers and shortcuts only for comments. (Falstad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re close..

1. AC couple into a zero crossing comparator that limits at given saturation of +/-13.5V =27Vpp
2. no need for a Schmitt as it gets integrated anyways in next stage and Hysteresis will cause amplitude controlled phase jitter if noise was  added to input signal. If it has DC offset, AC couple into some R to 0V.
3. choose the cap current equation wrt. Vpp swing which controlled by bipolar cap current step
4. Ic=CdV/dt the cap sees the output voltage 20Vpp or +/-10Vp with respect to the
   virtual ground which also happens to be Vin+=0V
5. dt= 5ms = 1/2f, for f=100,. **C=Ic * dt/dV** = 1mA * 5ms / 20V
6. Since square output current charges the cap relative to 0V , the resistor only sees the square wave voltage = +/-13.5Vp. Using the absolute constant current ramp from the bipolar square wave **|Ir|= Vp/R=  13.5V/R**
7. Ir=-Ic into Vin- ( now solve for RC)
8. Ic= C * 20V/5 ms = Ir = 13.5/R
9. RC = 13.5/20 * 5ms = 3.375ms
10. So consider 33k * 100nF = 3.3ms and tweak the difference
11. Since the integrator has >10^5 DC gain, add a Rfb about 30x Rin (then it’s hard to see nonlinearity, but actually easy to measure with cap current sag.
12. [Simulate](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0Y2BMBWBICMkEDYAscMGYUAOQrIwlAdjhApRAxAQgQFMBaFFAKAENUMIeDIRBwqIISJEo86EB1nIUsWPNkw8eBBTxwiysFkzhUKsFwDuo8bohjqk8FwBOEw9epwsd8RGW8JEkCsECwATgY8IOlFeRk5AxUoFQQwnSZDDBlcMLAMBj8zFw8JYWDSkUE8WEtQiPLwyLgIcwBjcts6ppbUaDN%202BR2CkZINK0BFAjNFARqMD7uKyiQzpWKp1d1rwhG0W8TRJqAcwbdBqxKpysUAQk51DgRLXmuU9vBII-Q25NzPToe3WqQcQT8IEIqm4ACUQPUXvRVg9wQZGId0BQwBRprhsZcIgV0LVtgd1p1zFY9jsuhJmk4AA4lLCXEqOQEMmmdATPOns8yM74I772VChTZwyIPFBPe7zRjmLZBbyfEJYc6FGoAe0eYr81QQ0gWWiwVANnG8ujKC0Ghy42r5jwQWAY8Qy4TCYUI2AoCAIYWSMDodlFeDtqDwusdztCYw9cZ9BEhJH91sDJmoMgkYYYIT1YG0AbAQb6himzPytC9FGwhBGwciIAAkq0uFFRH9TDAQNDIAAXCwsHgAay4QA) or build it. Verify all assumptions in your “spec” .That is usually much more detailed but this step is called DVT meaning ?(guess)
    [image]
13. Too late to ask for new specs like constant triangle wave for variable frequency.  remember ,always firm up all specs before starting design

All done. cheers.

### Post. Mortem

On 2nd thought the straight comparator with glitches from noise will round off the peaks and change the Vpp amplitude, so the comparator with %hysteresis greater than % (Noise/signal) in Vpp ratio is best even though it causes a phase shift.

Comment: I see, I realised a little too late and deleted my comment just before you replied.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I wasn't acquainted with the zero detector circuit until recently, so I was trying to use Schmitt in the first place. Anyways, thanks again!